# how do i return data from an arraylist after importing data from firebase?

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

Im trying to get data from firebase and add it to an arraylist to store it and use it in my code but when i add values to the arrayList and return it it returns an empty array and i don't know how to fix it.

This is the function i use to get the data from firebase:

at the moment i am just adding "Google" as a test but it is still returning an empty array. But when i add the value outside of the

```
myRef.addValueEvent listener(object: ValueEventListener {}
```

function it return the correct value

how can i get this data and return it as an arrayList to use ?

```
private fun getList() : ArrayList<String> {
    
    var list = ArrayList<String>()

    val myRef = database.getReference("User-following").child(currentUid!!)

    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                list.add("Google")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
    return list
}
```

Comment: To see what's going on, put some displays in your code, both just before returning the list, and inside the ValueEventListener methods.  You'll probably find that the event listener isn't called until _after_ your getList() function returns.

Comment: what do you mean by displays?

Comment: So i added a println() in my code and printed the data to see if it was working and i see that the function is printing the list before the println(). I replaced the add("google") with println(childSnapshot.value). how do i get it to add to the array before returning?

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and your `return list` runs before `list.add("Google")` ever gets called. For more on how to deal with this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519